# Write to custom.css in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. My blog has a theme named `canvas` and I have a file in `wp-content/themes/canvas/custom.css`. I want to be able to write to that file through wp-admin. 
How to do that?

Comment: And what have you done?Atleast google it

Comment: Can't you see "canvas" in the selector on the upper right corner of this page ? /wp-admin/theme-editor.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Apperance > Editor in the WP Admin panel. Select this and your CSS files should be displayed as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see the message: You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See the Codex for more information. Should I chmod 777 that file?